# Twitter Bootstrap image gallery not showing title

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, gallery

I go to http://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/ and click on the blue button that says Launch Image Gallery. I notice the images have titles.

I can get the images to work... but I can't display the titles or image captions. 
See: http://communitychessclub.com/chessresearcher/ and click on gallery tab in bootstrap navbar menu at the top. Images, yes... titles or captions... no.

I used chrome inspect element but it makes no sense to me.

Sample of my markup:

```
<div id="links">

<a href="images/Evening%20Park,%20Kharkiv_2011.JPG" title="Evening Park, Kharkiv 2011" data-gallery> </a>
<!--<a href="images/Main%20Photo.jpg" title="test" data-gallery> </a>-->
<a href="images/Kharkiv_2011.jpg" title="Kharkiv, 2011" data-gallery> </a>
<a href="images/Kharkiv_2013-1.JPG" title="Kharkiv, 2013" data-gallery> </a>
<a href="images/Kharkiv_2013.JPG" title="Kharkiv, 2013" data-gallery> </a>
<a href="images/Lavaur,%20France_2011-1.JPG" title="Lavaur, France 2011" data-gallery> </a>
<a href="images/Lavaur,%20France_2011.JPG" title="Lavaur, France 2011" data-gallery> </a>
<a href="images/New%20Year,%20Kharkiv_2012-13.JPG" title="New Year, Kharkiv 2012-13" data-gallery> </a>
<a href="images/Switzerland,%20Zurich_2011.JPG" title="Zurich, Switzerland, 2011" data-gallery> </a>
<a href="images/Winter,%20Kharkiv_2011.JPG" title="Winter, Kharkiv 2011" data-gallery> </a>

</div>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos, on your website.

When i checked it with Firebug I saw that the title is not being rendered at last please check it with your jquery plugins.

Comment: You were right! I commented out the  <!--<script>$('a').tooltip()</script>--> and now the titles show. But what am I going to do about tooltips now?

Comment: @verlager [You can refer here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips). Nothing is better than Twitter's own documentation :)